# Roslyn - Use VisualStudioWorkspace in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible somehow to use the VisualStudioWorkspace service, in an VsExtension that targets Visual Studio version 2010?(http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/Implementation/ProjectSystem/VisualStudioWorkspace.cs,e757fe6b8e91e765)

I tried to import the service using MEF, as described at https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/, but that's not working at all.

```
[Import(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace))] 
public VisualStudioWorkspace myWorkspace { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  VisualStudioWorkspace only exists in VS2015 and newer.